# How to log bugs in bugzilla through hudson?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, hudson, bugzilla

I need to run my automated scripts through hudson and if there is error while running that scripts the issue related to that should get automatically logged in to the bugzilla

Comment: So for every test failure you want a bug logged into BugZilla?

Comment: Yes, for every test failure i want to log a bug.